# Knockout Visible Binding Flop

Tags: html, knockout.js, visible

I'm trying to use the Visible Binding to hide any (deposit) values that are = 0 OR null. I continue to fail in my n00bish trial and-error attempts. Below is a snippet of the KO.

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: children">
<!-- ko with: propertyBag -->
<tr data-bind="visible: $data.LLC_BI__Deposit__c_LLC_BI__Amount__c.value != null"  style="">
<td data-bind="if: $data.LLC_BI__Deposit__c_LLC_BI__Account__c &amp;&amp; $data.LLC_BI__Deposit__c_LLC_BI__Account__c.value">
    <span data-bind="text: LLC_BI__Deposit__c_LLC_BI__Account__c.displayValue">
```

The idea is that there will be 5-6 Deposits listed, but any that have 0 or null values should be hidden. Is Visible the correct binding to use in this case? If so I would appreciate any tips. Thanks!

Comment: You are only testing for `null` not zero...

Comment: Please try to make sure it's easy (and pleasant) for us to help you, e.g. by including enough code to reproduce the issue (e.g. a corresponding view model, some basic bootstrapping, syntactically valid and runnable view code), but as reduced as possible (e.g. replace those very long unintelligable property names with something readable).

Answer (score 3):

You have several ways to display/hide elements.

[Visible](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/visible-binding.html) is one of them. It will make the element displayed or hidden (depending on your condition), but the underlying html will remain in the DOM.

[If binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/if-binding.html) is another, which creates or destroys the DOM elements instead of simply hide them.

As pointed in one comment, your condition is wrong, you just test for `null`. You should instead add an observable in your viewModel, which would contain the logic to display/hide the element. This allows you to test this property, as you may want to do.

Have a look at this simplified snippet:

```js
function accountVM(amount) {
  var _this = this;

  _this.balance = ko.observable(amount);

  _this.displayBalance = ko.computed(function() {
    return _this.balance() != null && _this.balance() !== 0;
  }, this);

  _this.decrement = function() {
    _this.balance(_this.balance() - 1);
  };
};

function myVM() {
  this.list = ko.observableArray([new accountVM(1), new accountVM(5), new accountVM(2), new accountVM(null)]);
};

ko.applyBindings(new myVM());
```

```css
div.element {
  background-color: yellow;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div data-bind="foreach: list">
  <div class="element" data-bind="visible: displayBalance, text: balance, click: decrement" title="decrement"></div>
</div>
```